# Expression tree select query

Tags: c#, expression

Hey I have a source with IQueryable

`var recommendedItems = (IQueryable)propertyResolverMethod?.Invoke(_propertyResolver, new object[] { itemId, ResolvedCollectionId });`

I know the returning type of items and that it has a field "Id" in it. And what I need if let's say it was just usual collection it's `recommendedItems.Select(i => i.Id)` but not in this case. Here I should use an Expressions.

Already made my property and a param

```
var someParam = Expression.Parameter(_itemType, "p");
var someProperty = Expression.Property(someParam, "Id");
```

Comment: What's the question then?

Comment: Can't you use expression in the simple way?
Expression<Func<Item, int>> = item => item.Id;